# SQLite .Net Framework Data Provider not found when installed programmatically?

Tags: .net, system.data.sqlite

I use SQLite (1.0.77.0) for a particular web service but for various reasons I can't touch the web.config file.  I worked around this by manually adding the provider programmatically using this code:

```
try
{
    var dataSet = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.data") as System.Data.DataSet;
    dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add("SQLite Data Provider"
    , ".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
    , "System.Data.SQLite"
    , "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite");
}
catch (System.Data.ConstraintException e) { /*...*/ }
```

This seems to work fine on my machine (Windows 7 Professional x64) even if SQLite is not deployed into the GAC, but when I try accessing the Provider Factory it fails on Windows 2003 SE SP2 with the exception message:

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

I've confirmed that it does work on that same machine if I add the relevant entries to the web.config file (adding it programmatically afterwards causes a ConstraintException, as expected).

What would cause this behaviour and is there a workaround?  I do not want to install SQLite into the GAC on the Windows 2003 server.

Answer (score 0):

I would just install the Sqlite DLL into the web application's bin directory. Then it should be automatically picked up by the .Net framework DLL resolution process.

Comment: The file does in fact reside there.